# entering a number into a query

Tags: php, mysql

I've been stuck at this for a while and I'm sure its a simple fix but I just can't find an answer for it.

I'm trying to remove a row in a table but the variable I'm putting into the query isn't being recognized. In the $remove query below, if I enter a number that corresponds to a row the query works fine, but when I use the variable it won't.

```
if (isset($_POST['remove']))
{

 $remove = $_POST['remove'];
 //echo $remove; print the number entered

 $query ="DELETE dogid FROM regdogs WHERE dogid = $remove ";
 if($query_run = mysql_query($query)){
 $query_num_rows = mysql_num_rows($query_run);

 if($query_num_rows==1)
      echo 'Entry removed ';
 else
      echo 'Not removed ';  
 }
```

Thanks

Comment: Is `dogid` numeric or a string?  If it's a string it needs quotes.  Also, if you're building all of your queries like that, you should google SQL-injection. Your queries are quite unsafe.

Answer (score 7):

```
$query ="DELETE FROM regdogs WHERE dogid = $remove ";
```

Try this. This is just a syntax error.

Again, please move to ***mysqli_*** methods. ***mysql_*** methods are deprecated.

Comment: or pdo, or at least protect entries

Answer (score 1):

I hope that this is an acceptable answer - since your question is how to add parameters to a query, I feel that it is related.

If you just add `$remove`, which is `$_POST['remove']`, you will allow users to execute arbitrary SQL commands. Imagine someone posted `1 OR 1=1` as the parameter. Your SQL query would say `DELETE dogid FROM regdogs WHERE dogid = 1 OR 1=1` and would delete the whole table. Instead, always use `mysql_real_escape_string` when working with user input. Your whole code would look like this:

```
if (isset($_POST['remove']))
{

 $remove = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['remove']);
 //echo $remove; print the number entered

 $query ="DELETE FROM regdogs WHERE dogid = $remove ";
 if($query_run = mysql_query($query)){
 $query_num_rows = mysql_num_rows($query_run);

 if($query_num_rows==1)
      echo 'Entry removed ';
 else
      echo 'Not removed ';  
 }
```

(Of course, everyone saying that mysql_* is deprecated, is absolutely right. I assume that you're just starting with PHP. Since most tutorials are still using mysql_*, that is absolute fine for now. Once you're more familiar with it, consider switching to mysqli or PDO.)

Answer (score 0):

query should be modified to

```
DELETE FROM regdogs WHERE dogid = $remove
```

try printing query

```
echo $query;
```

and

post the results.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need this:

```
 $query ="DELETE FROM regdogs WHERE dogid = $remove ";
```